# Creating a Bar Graph where each Bar is a Histogram

Tags: matlab, histogram, bar-chart

I'm creating a line plot, where the y value of each point is the average value of vector i. The x value of each point is i.

I want to visualise the distribution of numbers in each vector, preferably all on the same graph.

Is there a way I can make a bar graph, where each bar, i, is something like a colorbar, representing the histogram of vector i. So essentially I want to end up with 20 or so bars, each being a histogram.

Or if there is a better way to visualise numerous histograms on a single plot, I'd like to hear it.

Comment: If all your histograms use the same bins then what about a heat map (i.e. 2D flat image) where each column represent one histogram and you use colour to represent relative frequency?

Comment: I originally thought of using a heatmap, but this appears to be creating a graph where the range of y values is [1 end] of the vectors, and then the colours are the values in each cell. Whereas I wanted the reverse, that is the range to be [min(vector) max(vector)] and the colours to be counts of each distinct value. I guess I could sort each vector, and look at clumps of colours via the heatmap method.

Comment: I don't know about the `heatmap` method... I'm suggesting that you make all your histograms (using the same number of bins) lets say as column vectors, then concatenate them together into a 2D matrix, display it using `imshow` with your choice of `colormap`

Comment: if you can manage to rearrange your data properly you can consider using [**a histrogram of multiple columns**](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/ref/hist.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem using Dan's solution. I took a histogram of each vector (with specific bin intervals), and stored them all in a 2D matrix (Each column is a complete histogram). Then displayed it with image() (Don't have access to imshow).

I did have to mess around with the axis labels though, as the image() function was plotting it according to the coordinates of the 2D matrix, rather than the values in the original vectors. Fixed that up with some calls to set(gca,'YTickLabel/YTick'). Also had to set the YDir back to 'normal' rather than 'reverse'. I think image() was flipping it.